# Show that resolvant is analytic outside the spectrum

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $T$ be a bounded operator on $Hilbert$ space $\mathcal{H}$. Show that $R_{\lambda}=(T-\lambda)^{-1}$ is an analytic function on open set $\rho(T)=\mathbb{C}\setminus sp(T)$.
I know $R_{\lambda}=-\Sigma_{n\geq0}{\frac{T^{n}}{\lambda^{n+1}}}$ is analytic when $\left|\lambda\right|>\left\|T\right\|$ but I don't know how to deal with it when $\left|\lambda\right|\leq\left\|T\right\|$. Could anyone help me? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\lambda_0 \in \mathbb{C}\setminus \sigma(T)$. For $|\lambda - \lambda_0| < \frac1{\|R(\lambda_0)\|}$ we will show that $$R(\lambda) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (\lambda - \lambda_0)^n R(\lambda_0)^{n+1}$$

Verify that in general we have $R(\alpha) - R(\beta) = (\alpha - \beta)R(\alpha)R(\beta)$. This implies
$$R(\lambda)\big(I- (\lambda - \lambda_0)R(\lambda_0)\big) = R(\lambda_0)$$
Note that $\|(\lambda - \lambda_0)R(\lambda_0)\| < 1$ by assumption. Hence $I- (\lambda - \lambda_0)R(\lambda_0)$ is invertible with $$\big(I- (\lambda - \lambda_0)R(\lambda_0)\big)^{-1} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (\lambda - \lambda_0)^n R(\lambda_0)^{n}$$
Finally it follows
$$R(\lambda) = \big(I- (\lambda - \lambda_0)R(\lambda_0)\big)^{-1}R(\lambda_0) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (\lambda - \lambda_0)^n R(\lambda_0)^{n+1}$$
which implies that $R$ is analytic on $\mathbb{C}\setminus \sigma(T)$.